# How to develop npm module locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

Lets say im working on an app, MyApp, and I want to build an NPM module for it, MyModule. Right now I can think of two ways to develop it:

1. Makes changes -> save -> npm install /path/to/module in MyApp
2. Same as 1, except run npm install /path/to/module then editing it directly in node_modules then copying the changes over.

What I'd like is an easier workflow. One where I can simply save the file, refresh the page, and my changes are there. Is that possible? For example, I know in Gemfiles I can just link to another directory as the path. Pretty sure I can't do that with npm tho.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You're looking for the [`npm link` command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), which is a two steps process:

1. Run `npm link` from your `MyModule` directory: this will create a global package symlinked to the `MyModule` directory
2. Run `npm link MyModule` from your `MyApp` directory: this will create a `MyModule` folder in `node_modules`, symlinked to the global symlink (and thus to the real location of `MyModule`).

Comment: How would this reflect in the package.json, especially with regards to the module version, e.g. MyModule@1.2.6. E.g. in a microservice environment multiple MyApps would need to require different versions of MyModule. If they can't, changes in MyModule always directly influence ALL MyApps - which is exactly the opposite of what is wanted.

Comment: Do you have a best practice for debugging once it's linked other than `console.log()`? It would be great to be able to put break points in VS Code or something of the like. 

I have an open question if you'd like to refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453499/debugging-an-npm-module

Comment: `npm ls --link` can be used to check linked dependencies

Comment: `npm ls --global` was also useful.  It showed me a link to directory that holds the  `MyModule` package.

Answer (score 17):

To add on to Paul's answer, you can also do a shortcut for the above by doing the following from within your `MyApp` directory:

```
npm link ../MyModule
```