# How to execute npm module locally?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to write an npm module. However, the workflow is a little odd. I would like to just be able to execute my function after I make changes.

This is my index.js file so far:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

exports.run = () => {
  const array = [1, 2, 3];
  const double = _.map(array, x => x * 2);
  console.log("heyyyyyyyy: ", double);
};
```

Currently from what I can tell the only way to test this is by creating another npm module, `npm link` my original one, and then `npm link MyModule` from the 2nd one. (as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20888757/1555312)

This would be a headache to do in a team since I would have to explain to everyone that we need 2 modules just to test 1. Is there a way I can just run `npm run MyModule`? Or go into an npm console and run `const myModule = require("MyModule"); myModule.run()` every time I make a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `module.parent` to check if the file is being required or not and then run code inside that, e.g. something like below:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

exports.run = () => {
  const array = [1, 2, 3];
  const double = _.map(array, x => x * 2);
  console.log("heyyyyyyyy: ", double);
}

if (!module.parent) {
  exports.run();
}
```

Comment: How would you run the file though from your terminal?

Comment: Just run it with node, e.g. `node index.js` (or whatever the name of the file is)

Comment: Nice! This is perfect. Thanks

Comment: @Edmund You're welcome. Good luck with your coding! Also, I'd recommend https://github.com/substack/tape for testing.

Comment: Will this work with babel? I'm using `import` (ex: `import _ from "lodash"`)

Comment: It should work with babel since `module.parent` is just plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if I take out the contents of the method and run the file with `node index.js` it works!

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const array = [1, 2, 3];
const double = _.map(array, x => x * 2);
console.log("heyyyyyyyy: ", double);
```

Comment: But then you aren't exporting anything.

Comment: Yeh I think your way is better since that means I can either publish it on npm or let it be loaded in a script tag

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only to make it easier for you to run the code while actually developing it. Best way is to write some tests that runs your code, but if you start like this, it's simple to just extract that code into tests later on.