# How do I make my local JavaScript project consume a local library?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a JavaScript project, specifically, a `create-react-app` project, using yarn. I'm using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) in my project and I have an idea how to improve it. I cloned Yup to my local hard drive to be able to edit it and work on it, but how do I make my local project use the local copy of Yup instead of the one installed from the npm package into `node_modules`?

For those that know Ruby/Rails/Bundler, I'm after the JavaScript equivalent of

```
gem "somegem", path: "../../../somegem"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888576/how-to-develop-npm-module-locally

Answer (score 0):

You can use **npm link** to consume a local library