# localhost website and editing NPM package to later commit changes

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

Pardon the title, it's terrible.

Situation:

I pull a github repo that represents a website. I build it locally for development. It's running on localhost.

It uses webpack, and has a series of node modules loaded.

I need to edit one of those modules and see the results on that website.

I then need to push those changes to the repo that builds to the npm module.
Ideally I do the edits on the npm module as a local pull of that repo, and the local website is referencing those changes and webpack watch is rebuilding as I go along, then when all good, I can do a pull request to that npm module.

What do I use to do this? Is their a common workflow or term for this so I can figure out how?

Thank you.

Note: I attempted to use npm link,

I.e. in the repo "custom-npm" I typed "npm link"
Then in the website repo, in the node_modules/custom-npm folder I typed "npm link custom-npm"

error is: "custom-npm" is not in this registry

"custom-npm" is a github private package. Not sure if that does something here unintended...

Comment: See [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link)

Comment: Damn, that was fast. All right - so I did try NPM link... and from the output assumed I was barking up the wrong tree. Please see update to question.

Comment: you type `npm link` in the root of the `custom-npm` project, then in the root of the website's repo (_not_ in its node_modules dir, just the root dir for that project) you type `npm link custom-npm`.

Comment: Straight cutter. Thank you very much Mike. The only additional note, is that it's a private package on github, despite the repo name being "custom-npm" I need to type @my-org/custom-npm That worked parfe.

Comment: Should I just delete this question as useless or do you want to answer and I accept?

Comment: Let me find a good question to mark this a duplicate of. [How to develop npm module locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888576/how-to-develop-npm-module-locally) seems appropriate.